# Find Remote File Using Wildcard In Ansible

Tags: ansible

I run a java command using the shell module which creates a file with a random string suffixed to this.

I need to subsequently POST this file using the uri module.

I am trying to find the file using the [stat module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) and a wildcard but it isn't finding it.

```
- stat:
    path: "{{ my_dir }}/info-*"
  register: info

- debug:
    msg: "info isn't defined (path doesn't exist)"
  when: info.stat.exists == False
```

How else can I find the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *stat* module requires a full path. Use the [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) module instead. Quoting:

> **paths** List of paths of directories to search.

> **patterns** One or more (shell or regex) patterns, which type is controlled by use_regex option.
> The patterns restrict the list of files to be returned to those whose basenames match at least one of the patterns specified. Multiple patterns can be specified using a list. This parameter expects a list, ...

For example, find the `info-*` files in the directory `/tmp/test` and display the list of files

```yaml
    - find:
        paths: /tmp/test
        patterns:
          - "info-*"
      register: info

    - debug:
        var: info.files
```

Q: ***"I run a java command using the shell module which creates a file with a random string suffixed to this. I need to subsequently POST this file using the uri module."***

A: It is possible to use the first file from the list

```yaml
  my_file: "{{ info.files.0.path }}"
```

, but there might be more files matching the pattern `info-*`. A robust solution would be to make the `java command ... which creates a file with a random string suffixed` to return the filename. Or, it might be possible to use the [tempfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/tempfile_module.html#tempfile-creates-temporary-files-and-directories) module instead.

***Update***

There is the creation time attribute *ctime* in each of the files from the list `info.files`. You can [*sort*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.sort) the list by *ctime* and take the last one created

```yaml
  my_files: "{{ info.files|sort(attribute='ctime')|map(attribute='path') }}"
  my_file: "{{ my_files|last }}"
```

Be careful because this creates a race condition. Other processes may create newer matching files.

---

Given the tree

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── info-1
├── info-2
└── info-3
```

and the example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_files: "{{ info.files|sort(attribute='ctime')|map(attribute='path') }}"
    my_file: "{{ my_files|last }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: /tmp/test
        patterns:
          - "info-*"
      register: info

    - debug:
        var: my_files

    - debug:
        var: my_file
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [find] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_files:
  - /tmp/test/info-1
  - /tmp/test/info-2
  - /tmp/test/info-3

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  my_file: /tmp/test/info-3

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```